# How to get rid of "The solution you are trying to open is bound to source control" message

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a Visual Studio solution files copied from a source controlled solution. I don't want it to be source controlled and when I open it I get the message: `the solution you are trying to open is bound to source control`

I deleted the .vssscc files but still get the message. How can I get rid of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to clean the solution file (.sln) by removing the following GlobalSection:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 2
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = http://example.com/tfs/defaultcollection
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    /// --- more solution specific stuff omitted --- ///
EndGlobalSection
```

and you need to remove the source control references from every single project file (.csproj for C# projects):

```
...
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm in a multi-project solution.