# Unbind project from source control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I copied my project code into a new folder on my local computer - just a simple copy and paste.

When I open the project, I get a message that says:

> The solution you're opening is bound to source control...

However, when I go into `File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control`, I don't see any bindings. As a matter of fact, all the checkboxes next projects in my solution are unchecked and there's no "Unbind" option and in the Advanced menu, I see "Add to Source Control" option.

How do I remove this binding?

Comment: Might be the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883129/how-to-get-rid-of-the-solution-you-are-trying-to-open-is-bound-to-source-contro

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you!

Comment: @starain-MSFT SO converted that answer into a comment, haha.

Comment: @TobeO Maybe it is too short, you can try to add more information in the answer.